# compositions of n 'types' with int values that result in 10

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have $8$ different 'types' that each can have a count assigned of $0-10$.

I want to know how many compositions there are so that the sum of counts is always 10.

Example: a=> (10) and b through h=> (0) is valid, but a=> (10) and b=> (10) is not.

Comment: It would probably be easier to work with assigning integers $0$ to $10$ to these eight unknowns, to total $10$.

Comment: A better word than "combinations" here is [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) because the types are distinguished (which amounts to treating the order of assignments as important).

Comment: Switched to integers. 'Compositions' sounds about right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the possible assignments is discussed in many problems here with the "stars and bars" technique.

Consider ten stars and seven (one less than eight) bars arranged in a line.  There are $\binom{17}{7} $ possibilities.

Interpret the bars as separating the stars into eight summands from left to right corresponding to the eight types.

Comment: Thanks, besides your Wiki reference, this article is also quite good for understanding:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the number of ways of partitioning the number $10$ into integers. (Where we associate the value $n\times10\%$ to each integer $n$ to return to your original problem).

There are several possible answer depending on whether you allow for repeatition, and whether you include the number $0$:

- Ways of partitioning the number $10$ into distinct sums of integers $1\ldots 10$ is $P_{10}=42$ allowing for repetition. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html).
- Ways of partitioning the number $10$ into distinct sums of integers $0\ldots 10$ is infinite if we allow for repetition.
- Ways of partitioning the number $10$ into distinct sums of integers $1\ldots 10$ is $Q_{10}=10$ when we do not allow repetition. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html).
- Ways of partitioning the number $10$ into distinct sums of integers $0\ldots 10$ is $20$ when we do not allow repetition.

Comment: I don't think that answers my question.
Variables a through h have a value between 0 and 10 (both included).
The sum of all eight variables needs to be 10 (100% in my case).
How many combinations are there that lead to that sum of 10.
The variables themselves can't repeat, their respective values can.

Comment: These,are not partitions, but (weak) compositions of ten into eight summands.  See the link in my Comment on the Question.